# Spring Roo for a rich reporting app

Tags: java, spring, spring-roo

I'm thinking of using Spring Roo for a reporting app. This is a rich reporting app made up of a collection of master-detail forms that will export excel and pdf. This is a read-only app to an existing data warehouse.

My plan is to create a set of entities and then define a set of finders, where each finder represents one of the required reports. No idea how I am going to handle the master-detail display of the file export.

Anyone using roo willing to point out what my options are for master-detail and file export? Also, how good is roo for this type of app?

Answer (score 1):

I have used gvnix addons and they seem to serve the purpose you are looking for. Here is the link for the addons:

https://code.google.com/p/gvnix/wiki/DocPattern

Comment: Thanks. i wrote that app using spring and jasper without Roo and its been in production for a while now. I'll save this link for next time.